# prove if $f(x),f'(x),...,f^{(n-1)}(x),f^{(n)}(x)$ are all linearly dependent then $f(x)$ is expressible in terms of $a,x^{k},e^{ax},\sin(ax),\cos(ax)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function such that for some positive integer n, $f$ has $n$ linearly dependent derivatives. in other words, if

$f(x),f'(x),...,f^{(n-1)}(x),f^{(n)}(x)$ are all linearly dependent functions,

then $f(x)$ is expressible in terms of $a,x^{k},e^{ax},\sin(ax),\cos(ax)$, and any combination of such functions, where $a$ is a constant and $k$ is a positive integer. prove this statement.

should I use the wronskian? Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
The linear dependence implies that $f$ satisfies a linear, homogeneous, constant coefficient  ODE of the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k f^{(k)}(x)=0,$$
and we have a very good understanding of such equations.

Comment: But couldn't there exist other functions that have n linearly dependent derivatives?

Comment: @Te55eract Nope. Look up any standard ODE text, and it will tell you how to solve such equations.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of linear dependence amounts to the assertion that $f$ is a linear homogeneous ODE of the form

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i f^{(i)}(x)=0$$

Equations of this form have a very particular form, and the fact that all potential solutions have that form is given by the ODE uniqueness theorem.